# Cant view custom events on branch.io

Tags: ios, objective-c, branch.io

In `viewDidLoad` I've added an arbitrary event to test.
Why cant I see this event under `custom events` tab in live view on dashboard? I've configured everything correctly and set live and test keys in plist.

`[[BranchEvent customEventWithName:@"User_Scanned_Item"] logEvent];`

Comment: In my experience, Branch events aren't logged instantly, they can take up to a few hours to show up.

Answer (score 0):

The Branch dashboard does show analytics for attributed events on the Sources page. If your custom event is attributed to a Branch link, you should be able to view this data by enabling the custom event column on the top right corner.

You should also be able to view a stream of events on the Liveview by switching to the custom event tab. Data on the Liveview is not persisted and is helpful for development purposes.

You can write to integrations@branch.io if you have more questions.

Comment: The custom event is not attributed to a branch link. If that was the case I believe I would use `-(void)customEventWithName:(NSString * _Nonnull) contentItem:(BranchUniversalObject * _Nonnull`

Comment: Perhaps this is because its not attributed, but the sources page doesn't have a `custom events` column. I do want to incorporate deep links, but for right now I'd just like to create isolated events. It seems like I cannot do this and ALL analytics is driven through deep links. I'll reach out to support but I'd like to hear your take on this. What I'm trying to do is really bare bones.

Comment: You can create a custom event through branch without having deep links. When you trigger event did you check in liveview if you can see any logs there ?

Comment: Yeah, I've learned that live view doesn't persist data forever, and that there can also be a delay before data appears, but I have not seen any evidence of event being tracked. Im going to try using the API with callback so maybe I will receive an error in response.

Comment: Yes live view data doesn't persist for long. If you could see data logging in live view then your custom events are getting tracked in branch.